# How do I generate a new dataset based on subtracting values from existing columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Apologies if this is very basic, I'm quite new to R. I have a dataset including days, categories and values, like below.

| Day | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0.5 |
| 3 | A | 0.1 |
| 1 | B | 1 |
| 4 | B | 0.7 |
| 1 | C | 1.2 |
| 2 | C | 1 |
| 5 | C | 0.9 |

I want to create a column of the "difference", i.e. how much the value has decreased from day 1 to day N for each category (it will have as many rows as I have categories, so 3 rows in this example). For the categories with more than 2 dates, I want to just take the start date (day 1) and the end date, ignoring the dates in between. I suspect the mutate() function may be able to help me, but I am unsure how to direct it to take the start-end date range. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you provide desired output? what kind of df do you want to get? because it is little bit unclear what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find square brackets to be useful in this instance to be able to select the specific `Value`s within each `Category`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    summarise(diff_value = Value[which.max(Day)] - Value[Day == 1], .by=Category)

##  Category diff_value
##1        A       -0.4
##2        B       -0.3
##3        C       -0.3
```

Using `dat` from @Stefan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `filter` and `summarise` you could do:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  Day = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L),
  Category = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  Value = c(0.5, 0.1, 1, 0.7, 1.2, 1, 0.9)
)

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

dat |>
  # Filter for the first and the last day by Category
  filter(
    Day %in% range(Day),
    .by = Category
  ) |>
  # Get the difference in Value by Category
  summarise(
    diff_value = diff(Value),
    .by = Category
  )
#>   Category diff_value
#> 1        A       -0.4
#> 2        B       -0.3
#> 3        C       -0.3
```